# Creating a function in R returning a plot

Tags: r, function, boxplot

I want to create a function with 3 arguments: A dataframe and two strings of characters (df, FROM, TO). The function should create a boxplot of AIR_TIME per CARRIER for that route.

My code is:

```
dest_plot <- function(df, FROM, TO) {
  return(ggplot(df, aes(x = AIR_TIME, fill = CARRIER) +
      geom_bar()))
}
```

However, I get the following error: Error: Mapping should be created with aes() or aes_(). What do I need to change in my code, to produce a boxplot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear why you deleted the question once you got an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your parenthesis were out of place, and you can also specify `geom_boxplot()`

Try this:

```
dest_plot <- function(df, FROM, TO) {
  return(ggplot(df, aes(x = AIR_TIME, fill = CARRIER))) +
                  geom_boxplot()
}
```

Comment: You're right that there was a misplaced parenthesis, but I think this answer has a misplaced parenthesis too.  Try `return(ggplot(df, aes(x = air_time, fill = carrier)) +
                  geom_boxplot())`.